# Unable to update the work directory using repo

Tags: git, synchronization, repository

I have local project which is a git repository. I have added this local project to Android manifest file. Whenever there is a new commit in my local repository, I am able to fetch my local project using `repo sync -n <local project>`. However when I try to update the work directory using `repo sync -l <local project>` I get an error

> error.GitError: try rev-list ('^0f4e601043d095c8920dad010e5814ef22a20f45', 'HEAD', '--'): fatal: bad object 0f4e601043d095c8920dad010e5814ef22a20f45

Can anybody provide pointer to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue earlier today - I could not find the bad object, but it appeared to occur due to repo self-updating after putting all the projects in a headless state. Manually checking out master and doing a pull on all the sub-projects solved it for me.

If you are really lazy and have a lot of projects, the following bash command may make life easier:

```
for i in `ls -d */`; do cd $i; git checkout master; git pull origin master; cd ..; done;
```

**Note**: this command assumes that:

- You are in repo's base directory and all subdirectories are git projects
- You do not have any uncommitted changes (Use repo status to double check this)

It probably wouldn't be hard to make a script that was a bit more intelligent (recursion, looking for .git directory etc)